# How to format weight to display 2 decimal places in Orders Grid?

Tags: magento-1.9, order-grid

Currently my Orders Grid is set up to add a Weight column with the total order weight, but it is displaying with 4 decimal places and I would like to only display 2 decimal places.

`_prepareCollection`

```
$collection = Mage::getResourceModel($this->_getCollectionClass());
$collection->getSelect()->joinInner(array('order_address' => Mage::getSingleton('core/resource')->getTableName('sales_flat_order_address')),'order_address.parent_id = main_table.entity_id',array('company','telephone'))->group('order_address.parent_id');
$collection->getSelect()->join(array('sfo'=>'sales_flat_order'),'sfo.entity_id=main_table.entity_id',array('sfo.customer_email','sfo.weight')); 
$this->setCollection($collection);
```

`_prepareColumns`

```
...
$this->addColumn('weight', array(
        'header' => Mage::helper('sales')->__('Weight'),
        'index' => 'weight',
        'filter_index' => 'sfo.weight',
        'width' => '50px',
));
...
```

## What is the proper way to format the data in the grid?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

There are a couple of ways to do it.

### SQL-level

```
$collection->getSelect()
    ->columns(array('weight' => new Zend_Db_Expr("DECIMAL(weight, 2)")));
```

Here we re-define the weight column in the selection object to select `weight` as a float rounded to the nearest hundredth.

### Application-level

```
# Your block, _prepareColumns method
$this->addColumn('weight', array(
        'header' => Mage::helper('sales')->__('Weight'),
        'index' => 'weight',
        'filter_index' => 'sfo.weight',
        'width' => '50px',
        'renderer' => 'yourmodule/adminhtml_grid_renderer_yourblock',
                         |
));                      |
                         |
# Your renderer block <--|
class Namespace_Yourmodule_Block_Adminhtml_Grid_Renderer_Yourblock
    extends Mage_Adminhtml_Block_Widget_Grid_Column_Renderer_Abstract
{

    // Where $row is an order model
    public function render(Varien_Object $row)
    {
        return number_format($row->getWeight(), 2);
    }

}
```

Here we leverage Magento's column renderer feature to pass each row of the grid (order model in this case) through a custom block to manipulate and return the display value.

Comment: I tried setting this up at the SQL-level and it is an improvement, but still not working _quite_ ideally. It still allows 0 or 1 decimal points as well (56 or 56.2, for example). My exact implementation is `$collection->getSelect()->join(array('sfo'=>'sales_flat_order'),'sfo.entity_id=main_table.entity_id',array('sfo.customer_email','weight' => new Zend_Db_Expr("ROUND(sfo.weight,2)")));`

Comment: Sorry @travisw , try to use the `DECIMAL` function instead. I've updated my answer

Comment: @travisw, I also updated my answer to use `number_format` in the application-level example.

Comment: Using `DECIMAL` (still in the SQL level) instead of `ROUND` returns a syntax error from Magento. `SQLSTATE[42000]: Syntax error or access violation: 1064 You have an error in your SQL syntax;`

Comment: Application level worked perfectly after I set up a Renderer. Thanks!

Comment: Use `echo $collection->getSelect()->assemble()` and post the output. Maybe there's something wrong with your query and not the `DECIMAL` function

Comment: That's why I gave 2 solutions :-p Glad it worked!

Answer (score 2):

try adding **'type'     => 'number',**

```
...
$this->addColumn('weight', array(
        'header'    => Mage::helper('sales')->__('Weight'),
        'index'     => 'weight',
        'type'      => 'number', //This Line
        'filter_index' => 'sfo.weight',
        'width' => '50px',
));
...
```

Comment: Well, this sort of worked (partially). It appears to truncate any excess zeros, but it still allows more (and less than) 2 decimal places. I am wanting to display exactly 2 decimal places, regardless of value.

Comment: Then you'll have to cretae your own type renderrer.

Here are the available grid column types
 https://code007.wordpress.com/2012/07/16/grid-column-types-in-magento/


You can start here for a renderrer

http://inchoo.net/magento/how-to-add-custom-renderer-for-a-custom-column-in-magento-grid/

Answer (score 1):

In database, weight attribute have backend_type set to decimal.

To change the decimal precision of attributes that have a backend_type set to decimal,

You have to change the type of value in this table :

```
catalog_product_entity_decimal
```

If you have not change yet, you should see :

```
decimal(12,4)
```

In your case, you have to replace with

```
decimal(12,2)
```